# What's the difference between _set() and filter() using a Foreign Key in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have a User and Order model.
Order has a fk User.

What's the difference between doing

```
def getorders(request):
    user = request.user
    orders = user.order_set.all()
```

and

```
def getorders(request):
    user = request.user
    orders = Order.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Both will return the same result, no ?

So what's the benefits to use _set instead of filter ?

Comment: The two are equivalent, the former might be more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both will return the same result, no ?

**Yes**, the two will result in the same query.

> So what's the benefits to use `_set` instead of `filter`?

You can give the relation a different name with [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), for example:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='orders'
    )
```

In that case you access the orders with:

```
user.orders.all()
```

this code can be read as "*all the orders of user*" which is likely more clean than writing a queryset like `Order.objects.filter(user=user)`.